# First steps with ginn

Tags: touchscreen, multi-touch

I just installed ginn on my Ubuntu 18.04 with:

```
sudo apt install ginn
```

I found the configuration with:

```
cat /etc/ginn/wishes.xml
```

How do I start the program so that I can use multitouch gestures on the touch screen?

When I type:

```
ginn
```

I got:

```
usage: ginn <configxml>
Using wishes file /etc/ginn/wishes.xml
using default configuration file /etc/ginn/wishes.xml ... 
ginn
 global
  wish
   action
    trigger
    button
  wish
   action
    trigger
    button
   ...
   wish
    action
     trigger
     key
Button : 4 Button : 5 Button : 4 Button : 5 
Gestures subscribed:
Pinch,touch=2
Drag,touch=2
Rotate,touch=2
Pinch,touch=3
Tap,touch=4
Pinch,touch=4
Drag,touch=4
error subscribing to gestures
```

How do I start the program so that the gestures are always applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Install `ginn` as an autostart program under *Menu › Preferences › Startup Applications*, thereby activating it after the next login.